# ASP.NET MVC jQuery migration from 1.2.6 to 1.3.2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, intellisense

I have a problem with jQuery migration from 1.2.6 to 1.3.2 in my project. The intellisense for jQuery in VS doesn't work.

To test this issue I created new project, added jQuery to master page, built solution and checked intellisense - works OK.

After this I deleted in solution this files:

- jquery-1.2.6.js
- jquery-1.2.6.min.js
- jquery-1.2.6.min-vsdoc.js
- jquery-1.2.6-vsdoc.js

And added this:

- jquery-1.3.2.js
- jquery-1.3.2.min.js
- jquery-1.3.2.min-vsdoc.js
- jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js

I've corrected jQuery link in master page and build solution - intellisense for jQuery doesn't work.

What I have missed?

I use VS2008 SP1, MVC RC1.

**UPDATE:**
Now all work OK. I don't sure about solution but I think intellisense was repared when I opened all js files in VS.

**SOLUTION**
The reason was the conflict between jquery and jquery.ui
I've created empty vsdoc file for jquery.ui and the problem is eliminated.
I found this solution here:
http://arahuman.blogspot.com/2009/02/error-updating-jscript-intellisense.html

Comment: Please supply your references headers in your .js file and your master page <script> tags and how you have them setup.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have to install a new intellisense file. Check [this](http://blogs.ipona.com/james/archive/2009/01/14/jquery-1.3-and-visual-studio-2008-intellisense.aspx) out.

Comment: Yes, I've dowloaded new file from jQuery site.